# Unable to parse elements with : sign

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm unable to retrieve data from tags with the `:` sign next to the name. It would be nice to have the `avail` attribute from the `domain:name`element and the text from the `domain:reason`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
  <response>
    <result code="1000">
      <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData>
      <domain:chkData xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0 domain-1.0.xsd">
        <domain:cd>
          <domain:name avail="1">sdfgsdf.gr</domain:name>
          <domain:reason>Available Domain Name</domain:reason>
        </domain:cd>
      </domain:chkData>
    </resData>
    <extension>
      <extdomain:resData xmlns:extdomain="urn:ics-forth:params:xml:ns:extdomain-1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ics-forth:params:xml:ns:extdomain-1.1 extdomain-1.1.xsd">
        <extdomain:comment ref="sdfgsdf.gr">The Domain Name can be provisioned.</extdomain:comment>
      </extdomain:resData>
    </extension>
    <trID>
       <clTRID>ABC:cs-foh:10782</clTRID>
       <svTRID>212-123-176-gr</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

---

### Addendum

If I run this

```
    function iterate($xml , $space = '') {
        foreach($xml->children() as $child){
            echo $space.$child->getName();
            echo "<br />";
            iterate( $child , $space.'--' );
        }
    }
```

I get this result.

```
response
--result
----msg
--resData
--extension
--trID
----clTRID
----svTRID
```

Why `domain:tags` are not consider as elements?

Comment: have you checked this http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Retrieving-Attribute-Values-P411.html

Comment: Hint for search: those are *namespaces*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple problem regarding the usage of XML namespaces, just take a look at this code snippet to workaround it:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
  <response>
    <result code="1000">
      <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData>
      <domain:chkData xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0 domain-1.0.xsd">
        <domain:cd>
          <domain:name avail="1">sdfgsdf.gr</domain:name>
          <domain:reason>Available Domain Name</domain:reason>
        </domain:cd>
      </domain:chkData>
    </resData>
    <extension>
      <extdomain:resData xmlns:extdomain="urn:ics-forth:params:xml:ns:extdomain-1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ics-forth:params:xml:ns:extdomain-1.1 extdomain-1.1.xsd">
        <extdomain:comment ref="sdfgsdf.gr">The Domain Name can be provisioned.</extdomain:comment>
      </extdomain:resData>
</extension>
  <trID>
    <clTRID>ABC:cs-foh:10782</clTRID>
    <svTRID>212-123-176-gr</svTRID>
  </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('domain', 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0');
$domain_name = $sxe->xpath('//domain:name');

echo $domain_name[0]->attributes()->avail;
```

#### Output

```
1
```

Comment: I get `Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found` . The `xml string` is exactly as I post it above.

Comment: If you use my code exactly as is the output is `1`, which is the value of the attribute you're looking for. What line throws that error? There's no `'&lt;'` in the XML code you showed.

Comment: There is another line above the `XML`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
     $string = <<<XML
     <domain:name avail="1">sdfgsdf.gr</domain:name>
     XML;

     $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
     foreach($xml->domain[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
         echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
     }
?>
```

Comment: For future reference.. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php , dont neglect the original source ^^

Comment: @acudars Where do I go from here `xml->response->resData` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302) is a helpful blog.

And the solution I came out.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

$avail = $xml->response->resData
->children('urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0')
->chkData->cd->name->attributes()->avail;

$reason = (string) $xml->response->resData
->children('urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0')
->chkData->cd->reason;

echo $avail;
echo "<br />";
echo $reason;
```

Result

> 1
>
> Available Domain Name

*Thanks to @ÁlvaroG.Vicario.*